# The state diagram of DFA

Tags: automation, dfa

Give a state transition diagram of DFA that recognizes the following language over the alphabet {x,y}

1. `L1` = the set of all strings that start with x and have odd length
2. `L3` = the set of all strings that end with x and have even length

And I need to find `L1 U L3`.

This is my answer:

[image]

The left part of my answer is `L1`(Maybe I can ensure the correctness of it), I'm confused about its correctness on right part, my answer is right or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is wrong. You can tell by thinking of words that should be in the language that the DFA doesn't accept, such as `xx`, which is a string of even length ending in `x`, so it is part of `L3`. You're also missing `yyyx`, which should be part of `L3`.

What you'll want to do is start with an epsilon-NFA, where the start state has two epsilon transitions to the start states of `L1`'s and `L3`'s start states. Then use the NFA-to-DFA algorithm to come up with a DFA that accepts `L1 U L3`.